# spawning multiple python processes/daemons of same name (different args)

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I am trying to create independent processes in python. These processes are a python script that I want to have multiple instances of, but instantiated with different arguments.
Simply, from a for loop, I am calling subprocess.Popen(), but with args varying accordingly:

```
for d in mylist:
    subprocess.Popen(['./subscriber.py', d.arg1, a.arg2, d.arg3])
```

In subscriber.py, I have code that "daemonizes" the process as per various [recipes](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/)
Alternatively to this, I have also tried to launch my subscriber.py with:

```
for d in mylist:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=subscriber.start,
                                args=(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3))
    p.daemon=True
    p.start()
```

My script also uses python logging to write to a common log file.

What happens with either method, is that only the process from the last iteration of my loop is left actually running. All I need is to have these background daemons running "forever", but I can only ever get 1 instance! [edit] Importantly, I want the calling thread to terminate, leaving this bunch of running daemons behind, running..

I have googled far and wide, on stackoverflow and elsewhere, can't seem to find a similar example. Perhaps its my python novice-ness .. is my approach completely incorrect?

Environment: - Python-2.7, ubuntu linux

Comment: Have you tried making a list of processes instead of reassigning the variable? eg. p.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=subscriber.start,args=(d.arg1, d.arg2, d.arg3)))

Comment: Ok, but I would like the calling thread to terminate, leaving a bunch of running daemons behind. This is why I lean towards Popen() as multiprocessing seems to not allow child processes running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not really need a Python-only solution, a tiny shell script may do the job:

```
while read ARGS; do
  nohup ./subscriber.py $ARGS &
done < mylist.txt
```

where `mylist.txt` contains arguments for each `subscriber.py` instance on a separate line.

[`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) "daemonizes" any command and `&` pushes it to the background. This means when the session which spawned that command ends, the nohup-ed command becomes a child of the init process (PID=1) and keeps running.

Comment: seems to behave the same way. If I try to manually launch subscriber.py from the command line with >nohup subscriber.py x y z &, followed by >nohup subscriber.py a b c &, .. The ps command only reveals 1 instance of subscriber.py running (the a b c version)!

Comment: Does it mean subscriber.py controls how many instances can exist? Also, when `&` is run, it shows the spawned process' pid (e.g. `nohup sleep 3 & ... [1] 31080`) and display a message when it finishes (e.g. `[1]  + 31080 done       nohup sleep 3`). You are saying 'x y z' instance dies quickly. That means you should be seeing such `[<jobid>] + <pid> done ...` message.

Answer (score 0):

2 things (besides appending the processes to a list which was mentioned above):

1. setting daemon=True actually means the opposite of what you expect. from the manual: `When a process exits, it attempts to terminate all of its daemonic child processes.`. Yup! Also, deamons can't spawn children.

which brings me to:
2. What you should do is spawn children that have daemon=False, and each of them, upon start, will daemonize using fork(). like so:

```
    def daemonize():

        pid = os.fork()
        if pid != 0:
            sys.exit(0)


        return pid
```